How to create an uninitialized 2D array?
C# allows you to create an array without it being initialized with GC.AllocateUnitializedArray<T>. T can be any type, such as bool or int. However, I do not know of a way to do this to a 2D array, e.g. bool[,] or int[,].
I know that I could allocate a 1D array that is the size of the 2D array, and then access it like it was a 2D array, like this:
int[] array = GC.AllocateUninitializedArray<int>(width * height); //width and height are width and height of the array
// ... (array is initialized)
int arrayAccessExample = array[x * height + y]; //x and y are anything greater than 0 and less than width and height, respectively

But that's annoying to constantly do, and could easily lead to bugs if done wrongly. I could make the array access into a function, which would remove the potential for bugs, but that's still inconvenient and I'd rather just be able to use a real 2D array. Is there a way to allocate an uninitialized 2D array directly, or to "cast" a 1D array into a 2D array?

I would consider going down this path to make it easy for you:
public class UnallocatedArray<T>
{
    public UnallocatedArray(int width, int height)
    {
        array = GC.AllocateUninitializedArray<T>(width * height);
        this.Width = width;
        this.Height = height;
    }
    
    private int Width { get; init; }
    private int Height { get; init; }
    
    private T[] array = null;

    public T this[int x, int y]
    {
        get => array[x * this.Height + y];
        set => array[x * this.Height + y] = value;
    }
}

Then you'd be able to write:
var ua = new UnallocatedArray<int>(4, 5);
ua[2, 1] = 42;
Console.WriteLine(ua[2, 1]);


Thanks for the quick answer! Are you sure it isn't possible to do a cast from a 1d array to a 2d array? If not, it's fine -- your code works great. (edit: Charlieface, I didn't know Span2D existed, thanks!)

It is worth noting row/column major order, since this can have an impact on interoperability. The built in 2D array, and your example, is column major. While things like images are almost always row major.


Is there a way to allocate an uninitialized 2D array directly?

No, not possible at all. While the code is "kind-of" there internally in the AllocateArrayEx function in gchelpers.cpp, the optional flags parameter is not exposed by any FCall or QCall function. Therefore it's not possible to do this even using reflection without recompiling the CLR.
You can and should open a GitHub issue requesting this feature, as it seems fairly simple to implement.

or to "cast" a 1D array into a 2D array?

Also no. They are completely different types, and even have entirely different allocation paths: SZArray (1D, zero-based) and other arrays.
I suppose in theory you could allocate a normal array, then do some horribly unsafe messing with the m_pMethTab to replace it with  a different one, and just hope it all "works", but I wouldn't use that in production.

But in my opinion, if your performance requirements are high enough to require uninitialized arrays then you probably don't want normal 2D arrays anyway as they have a significant overhead, due to the lack of optimizations in the runtime for multi-arrays.
There is also the Span2D type in the Microsoft.Toolkit.HighPerformance library, or you could create your own (a struct would probably be faster than a class like @Enigmativity has), to allow you to treat a 1D-array as 2D. You may still need to code carefully to avoid lots of unnecessary bounds-checking.
